# SQL Get All Data With The Given IDs And With The Same Data On Single Column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query

So, basically, I have this table

```
+-------------------
|id  | col1 | name |
|----|------|------|
| 1  |  a   |  la  |
| 2  |  b   |  ria |
| 3  |  w   |  la  |
| 4  |  q   |  la  |
| 5  |  y   |  ria |
|____|______|______|
```

And, what I want to do is, I want to get all the data based on id 1, 3 and 5 but with the same name. So, since id 5 is different, and id 1 and 3 is the same, I would like to exclude the id 5. I tried with `...HAVING COUNT(name) >=1` but it only shown 1 data. Is it possible? If so, how to achieve this? Thank you

EDIT:
So, what I mean is, I would like to get the result with the same name. Like:

```
+-------------------
|id  | col1 | name |
|----|------|------|
| 1  |  a   |  la  |
| 3  |  w   |  la  |
|____|______|______|
```

But, if, for instance in the future, there are case like

> "select all data from table where id `[1,2,3,5]` with the same data in `name` column"

this will cause a conflict (i guess). the point is, I would like to get the data with the same name where id is given (because I have php app, and the input from the user is only id, and user don't want the different name appear in the result).

Answer (score 0):

It is not absolutely clear what you expect as `la` should yield te result f 1,3,4 see query below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`id` int, `col1` varchar(6), `name` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`id`, `col1`, `name`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('1', 'a', 'la'),
>     ('2', 'b', 'ria'),
>     ('3', 'w', 'la'),
>     ('4', 'q', 'la'),
>     ('5', 'y', 'ria');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id 
> FROM table1 
> WHERE `name` IN (SELECT `name` FROM table1  GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 2)
> AND id IN (1,2,3,5)
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  3 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `name` FROM table1  GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 2
> ```
>
> ```
> | name |
> | :--- |
> | la   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6adca528b468ac08f4301ce94a8492d)*

Comment: I already tried with this query, but it only display one data. I updated the post too. Thanks!

Comment: @Fahmi you should eplained that a bit earlier, i updated the query to fit yur wishes

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable for the `id` values and query to get the `name` as per your query criteria. For example, using `mysql` client:

```
SET @ids = '1,3,5'; -- or SET @ids = '1,2,3,5';

SELECT DISTINCT(name)
FROM t1
WHERE
name IN (
  SELECT name 
  FROM t1 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(TRIM(CAST(id AS CHAR(5))), @ids) 
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
)
AND FIND_IN_SET(TRIM(CAST(id AS CHAR(5))), @ids);
```

The result depending upon the `@ids` input variable.

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| la   |
+------+

+------+
| name |
+------+
| la   |
| ria  |
+------+
```